# Logout issue with springboot and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, spring-boot

I had an issue regarding the logout . Once i am done with my logout and it's not popping me agin to enter the user name and password , why is it so ?
ttps://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2-vanilla

https://github.com/sharmaritesh/spring-angularjs-oauth2-sample

is it not the expected behaviour ? If so please suggest me what to do when i want to do the complete logout that means we have to delete refresh tokens as well i guess. the reason of not asking the username and password in my perspective , It's refresh token is valid and once i click teh login button it directly redirects me to the greeting page with generating the new access token with the help of refresh token.

But i would like to do the complete log out i.e, once the use clicks the logout and user should be able to enter his credentials to get the new refresh token and access token irrespective of the old refresh token expiration.

I really appreciate your help..!!!!

Thanks
Prince

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest posting all of the relevant HTTP traffic flow between client (browser) and server, both the redirects and "back end" traffic.

So, basically take the approach of knowing little about the actual implementation of the client and server, and just focus on the OAuth2 authorization code flow, its a protocol after all. Without this we'll be stabbing in the dark.

In terms of an answer, as a guess the client application may be passing a cookie to the authorization server and your just not seeing it. This is exactly what happened to me with Spring Boot and WSO2 IS 5.1.0